# SharePoint 2013 user log out after few seconds

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2013

We have a SharePoint intranet in which user gets logout after few seconds on login.  Its a custom template in which we have 2 options to login using FBA which is for users not part of company and Claim Based NTLM for users which are part of company. Issue is only with NTLM when user log in he browse few pages or just refresh the page, he logs out.

Distributed Cache is working fine
Kindly provide opinion where should i look

Comment: do you have multiple WFE in your farm ?

Comment: Server was on farm and shifted to standalone. Problem started after migration

Comment: Do you need both authentication on standalone server ?

Comment: Yes we require both, because FBA for clients and Windows Claim for Employee

Comment: Does standalone with 2 auth cause problem???

Comment: I believe from my experience, since you moved your server from multi server to standalone, there is possibility request is going on server which is not there anymore. Can you check with network team, your site address on load balancer is configured to hit your standalone server only ?